# How to start Timer Once session start

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, session

I have this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var minutesLabel = document.getElementById("hours");
    var minutesLabel = document.getElementById("minutes");
    var secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");
    var totalSeconds = 0;
    setInterval(setTime, 1000);

    function setTime() {
        ++totalSeconds;
        secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds%60);
        minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds/60));
    }

    function pad(val) {
        var valString = val + "";
        if(valString.length < 2) {
            return "0" + valString;
        } else {
            return valString;
        }
    }
</script>
```

I want to start this timer once user session starts and keep alive until session is not destroyed even if user close page or go to other pages.

Comment: so you need something on the server side for that

Answer (score 1):

add in a session variable say

```
$_SESSION['startTimer'] = microtime(true)
```

and then at the end of session you can calculate the time in microseconds as

```
$totalTime = microtime(true) - $_SESSION['startTimer']
```

Comment: assuming you are using session_start